# WPF : Как сделать привязку SystemColors в DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

В приложении используется DataGrid в котором отображаются строки. Задача сделать так, что бы выделенная строка SelectedItem отображалась цветом, вне зависимости доступен ли DataGrid в данный момент или нет. При этом в приложении есть ночная тема, в которой цвета должны быть другими. Я создал класс ColorThemeManager, в котором хранятся цвета для обеих тем. В основном коде привязка прекрасно работает

```
<Window Background="{Binding ColorThemeManager.MainBackGroundColor}">
```

Но с DataGrid привязка не срабатывает :

```
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentTestDevice.TestsSpecifications}">
                          <DataGrid.Resources>
                              <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{Binding ColorThemeManager.SelectedRowColor"/>
                              <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{Binding DataContext.ColorThemeManager.SelectedRowColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                              <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{Binding DataContext.ColorThemeManager.SelectedRowForegroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                              <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
                          </DataGrid.Resources>
                                  ...
                    </DataGrid>
```

Пробовал по разному. Срабатывает только вариант указать цвет явно, как в последнем варианте.
Как правильно выполнить Binding в этом случае? Или есть какой-то ещё способ задать цвет выделенной строки и её текста?

Comment: А приведите код `ColorThemeManager` и `ViewModel` этого окна

Comment: Не уверен, как это лучше выложить? ColorThemeManager это 400 строк кода. Даже если всё посокращать, не даёт в комментарий вставить. А ViewModel больше ещё на порядок.

Comment: `public class ColorThemeManagerClass : INotifyPropertyChanged` вот его сигнатура. В нём свойства цветов и метод который переключает с одной цветовой схемы на другую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще использовать слой `ViewModel` для хранения конкретных цветов для ночной и дневной темы не самая лучшая идея. Цвета - это всё же ответственность слоя `View`. Мы можем задать разные стили для дневной и ночной тем:

```
<Style x:Key="darkTheme">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                         Color="Red"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
                         Color="Yellow"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="mainTheme">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                         Color="Blue"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
                         Color="Green"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

`ViewModel` будет содержать лишь флаг `IsDark`, который даст понять, какой из стилей выбрать, а выбор стиля сделаем по триггеру:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDark}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" 
                    Value="{StaticResource darkTheme}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDark}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" 
                    Value="{StaticResource mainTheme}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Ну а эти три стиля поместим или в отдельный словарь стилей и подключим к окну, или в ресурсы окна:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="darkTheme".../>
    <Style x:Key="mainTheme".../>
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid".../>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Кажется получилось. Я правда стиль прям в DataGrid вставил, т.к. их на форме несколько, а подобный эффект нужен только у одного
`<DataGrid.Style>
 <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
  <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource mainTheme}"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatesFlags.IsNightMode}" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource darkTheme}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.Style>`